# SqlDataAdapter.Fill fails fails in multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, sqldataadapter

Can someone explain me why SqlDataAdapter.Fill fails in multithreading? I've prepared an example in LinqPad:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<DB>;Integrated Security=True";
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

var lck = new object();
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for(var i=0; i<64; i++)
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select {0}", i), connection))
    using(var ds = new DataSet())
    using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        //lock(lck)
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
    Console.Write("Ok ");
}));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

It gives me different errors all the time. And sometimes just hangs.
[image]

But if you uncomment the commented lock statement - everything will work fine.

Comment: Do you have MARS enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets

Comment: You are sharing an `SqlConnection` which is not thread safe. Create one as needed, pooling will optimise this.

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks share the `SqlConnection`. When the tasks run concurrently each one opens a data reader (by using `SqlDataAdapter`). The exception occurs because this is not allowed. Only one data reader may be open.

As far as I know there are 2 ways to solve it:

1. Open a new connection in each task.
2. Activate MARS, i.e. add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to your connection string.